# What does the output of rsync look like when it completes successfully?

Tags: backup, external-hard-drive, rsync

I used rsync to back up my main drive to an external drive last night. At some point in the night the external drive was unplugged. This is the tail of the output of `rsync -avRP`

```
...
/media/winter14/flickr/ren_desktop/test1.py
        1945 100%   12.18kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#474913, to-check=2/1256522)
/media/winter14/flickr/ren_desktop/test_start.py
         445 100%    2.73kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#474914, to-check=1/1256522)
/media/winter14/flickr/ren_desktop/time-test.py
        2494 100%   14.94kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#474915, to-check=0/1256522)

sent 79538570122 bytes  received 11368753 bytes  11208163.28 bytes/sec
total size is 191343688116  speedup is 2.41
```

Does this output indicate that the rsync completed successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output indicates only that `rsync` finished without crashing.  To know more, you need its exit status.

If you haven't run any other commands in that shell since `rsync` finished, you get the exit status of the last command with

```
echo $?
```

`rsync` can return a number of different exit codes which tell you what happened.  Here's an extract from its man page:

```
   0      Success
   1      Syntax or usage error
   2      Protocol incompatibility
   3      Errors selecting input/output files, dirs
   4      Requested action not supported: an attempt was made to manipulate 64-bit files on a platform that cannot  support
          them; or an option was specified that is supported by the client and not by the server.
   5      Error starting client-server protocol
   6      Daemon unable to append to log-file
   10     Error in socket I/O
   11     Error in file I/O
   12     Error in rsync protocol data stream
   13     Errors with program diagnostics
   14     Error in IPC code
   20     Received SIGUSR1 or SIGINT
   21     Some error returned by waitpid()
   22     Error allocating core memory buffers
   23     Partial transfer due to error
   24     Partial transfer due to vanished source files
   25     The --max-delete limit stopped deletions
   30     Timeout in data send/receive
   35     Timeout waiting for daemon connection
```

Comment: Excellent answer! It looks like the exit status was 0, so that's good.